# how to make a dns-sd afp register and save it on Mac OS X

Tags: mac

please I have a MacPro 2013 working as a server and four iMacs as clients. All computers are attached through network cables in a 1GB switch. Please I wanna create a register in dns-sd and, for the iMacs see in filder a server icon, like a xserver

i've tried do this command:

## dns-sd -R server  _afpovertcp._tcp local 548 model=xserver

It works but when I restart the machine, the register fades away. I wanna save this register.